# Why my program alerting undefined value

Tags: javascript

```
var cars = ["nano", "bmw"];
var bikes = ["pulsar", "splander"];
var con = [];
var foundCars = [];
var foundBikes = [];
var notFoundTransport =[];
for(var i = 0; i<cars.length; i++){
    con = prompt("enter your tranport name");
    if(con[i] == cars[i]){
    foundCars.push(con[i]);
    } 
}
for(var i = 0; i<2; i++){
alert(foundCars[i]);
}
```

Why it shows the undefined value after alerting foundcars array
eg, nano bmw 
it's alert, undefined, undefined
Please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: because `con[i] == cars[i]` is never true, after the prompt `con` is a string while `cars` is still an array.

Comment: What I have to do to make con array and push value in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check:

```
var cars = ["nano", "bmw"];
var bikes = ["pulsar","splander"];
var con = [];
var foundCars = [];
var foundBikes = [];
var notFoundTransport =[];
var found = false;
var checkExist = false;


for(var i = 0; i<2; i++){
    con[i] = prompt("enter your tranport name");
}

for(var i = 0; i<con.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j<con.length; j++){
        if(con[i] == cars[j]){
            foundCars.push(con[i]);
            found = true;
            checkExist = true;
        }else if(con[i] == bikes[j]){
            foundBikes.push(con[i]);
            found = true;
            checkExist = true;
        }else if(con[i]!=cars[j]&&con[i]!=bikes[j]&&found==false&&j!=0){
                notFoundTransport.push(con[i]);
                found = true;
        }
    }
        found = false;
}

console.log(foundCars);
console.log(foundBikes);
console.log(notFoundTransport);
```

Comment: `foundCars` in sometime is null and `for(var i = 0; i<2; i++)console.log(foundCars[i]);` is undefined,should used `foundCars.length`

Comment: I am trying to focus on the goals of the user, not on the current problem. I have copied what he has written and added my lines of code as a suggesttion, I find the question rather ambiguous which might led us teaching him the wrong approach. That is why I am asking him his primary goal.

Comment: hi, Arzgethalm       i am trying to do when user enter the value it's check with cars array and bikes array if value is matched with cars array it store in foundcars array if matched with bikes array store in foundBikes otherwise store in notFoundTransport

Comment: Now that clears it up. please check the updated answer if correct.

Comment: Prompt is getting only one value i have to enter more than one value.

Comment: I have to enter 2 values length of predefined array eg:- cars or bikes

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer, please check if it suites your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much  Arzgethalm

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add the result of the prompt to a proper place in the con array.

Then you should iterate through the array having in mind the length of the foundCars, not hard-coded 2.

```
var cars = ["nano", "bmw"];
var bikes = ["pulsar", "splander"];
var con = [];
var foundCars = [];
var foundBikes = [];
var notFoundTransport =[];
for(var i = 0; i<cars.length; i++){
    con[i] = prompt("enter your tranport name");
    if(con[i] == cars[i]){
        foundCars.push(con[i]);
    } 
}
for(var i = 0; i<foundCars.length; i++){
    alert(foundCars[i]);
}
```

Comment: excuse me for voted down.was wrong,and now i can not remove this

Comment: If you want to remove the downvote, you either upvote or re-downvote(it will remove it)

Comment: no,only i can remove down vote  after edit your post,say error that vote is lock

Comment: you might want to replace:for(var i = 0; i<foundCars.length; i++){
    alert(foundCars[i]);
} with just alert(foundCars); or use console.log(foundCars);

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yc5aq8yt/9/)

because `foundCars` is null for ever

you should use like this for found cars.

```
for(var i = 0; i<cars.length; i++){
    con = prompt("enter your tranport name");
    for(var p = 0; p<cars.length; p++){
       if(con == cars[p]){
         foundCars.push(con);
       } 
    }
}
```

and use `for(var i = 0; i<foundCars.length; i++)` insted of `for(var i = 0; i<2; i++)`